# using ros opencv standalone

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is it possible to use the opencv inside the ros package as a standalone tool? For some simple projects I only want to use opencv functions without using any ros functionality. I think that it is not possible to have opencv_ros and standalone opencv distribution together in the same computer so the only option is to be able to use the opencv_ros as a standalone tool.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38921/using-ros-opencv-standalone/) by [hkaraoguz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2853/hkaraoguz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since ROS Electric, the stand-alone `opencv` library is treated as a system dependency, installed like any other library for your Linux distribution. (You didn't say which one you are using.)

So, yes you can use `opencv` without ROS.

But, you will *not* be able to use the [opencv_bridge](http://ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge) interface without ROS.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can certainly use opencv separately using the opencv libraries that come with ros. Use rosmake to compile( remember to add executable in the CMakeLists) and run the executable from the bin folder. It is very useful for initial test to avoid going deep into the node and connections stuff.

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1